# Javascript: What are multi-level prototype hierarchies and why we should avoid it

Tags: javascript, coding-style, prototype-programming

In the [Google Javascript Coding Guidelines](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml?showone=Multi-level_prototype_hierarchies#Multi-level_prototype_hierarchies), it said that we should not use Multi-level prototype hierarchies because "These hierarchies are much harder to get right than they first appear!". Actually I didn't get what it means. Where can I find a good example to explain its usage and illustrate its bad effect?

Comment: Are you familiar with the basics of prototypal inheritance?

Comment: What kind of reason is that? Once you know how to do them right, you're fine.

Comment: It doesn't say you shouldn't use them. It just says you should use a library. The short summary "Not preferred" is misleading, and probably refers to manual fiddling.

Answer (score 5):

This is an example of two-level inheritance:

```
// 1. level constructor
var Dog = function ( name ) {
    this.name = name;
};

Dog.prototype.bark = function () { /* ... */ };

// 2. level constructor
var TrainedDog = function ( name, level ) {
    Dog.apply( this, arguments ); // calling the super constructor
    this.level = level;
};

// set up two-level inheritance
TrainedDog.prototype = Object.create( Dog.prototype );
TrainedDog.prototype.constructor = TrainedDog;

TrainedDog.prototype.rollOver = function () { /* ... */ };

// instances
var dog1 = new Dog( 'Rex' );
var dog2 = new TrainedDog( 'Rock', 3 );
```

Here, `dog1` inherits the `bark` method from the `Dog` prototype, and `dog2` inherits both that method (from the `Dog` prototype) and the `rollOver` method from the `TrainedDog` prototype.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the article is referring to not manually setting up the prototype chains but using a library, like `goog.inherits` or `util.inherits`

manually you would have to do

```
var Child = function Child() { ... };

Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
// for some common value of extend
extend(Child.prototype, {
  ...
});
```

This can be simplified to

```
var Child = function Child() { ... };

goog.inherits(Child, Parent);
extend(Child.prototype, {
  ...
});
```

Note here `goog.inherits` also deals with `Object.create` emulation in legacy browsers.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of prototype chain resolution problem. When you have something like `foo.bar` it doesn't mean that `bar` property belongs directly to `foo` object, so it start to search for `bar` in prototype chain of `foo`. If chain is long then property resolution could be relatively long operation.

Comment: But that isn't a problem with "getting it right" so much as just a potential performance issue. Could you talk a little more about it?

Comment: It's not a performance issue in any sensible browser, prototype chains are highly optimised.